# Error: h.playTouchSound is not a function?

Tags: react-native, error-handling, typeerror

I have a project using react-native. Sometimes when I run this project, it says:[TypeError: h.playTouchSound is not a function. (In 'h.playTouchSound()', 'h.playTouchSound' is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P3Tt.png)

I found this function in android\app\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle.
To fix this error, I tried to use gradlew clean and rebuild apk. How to handle this error? Is this error will sometimes showing up after production?

Comment: Hi! I'm facing same issue. Have you fixed it somehow? It appears always when I build release Android app.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I'm on 0.64.0 and Can't seem to find anything on it.

Comment: i am also getting same bug on my android device.  Did you able to get a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case upgrading gradle helped right away!

From:

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
```

To:

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
```

In buid.gradle android project file

This also forced to change distributionUrl in /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file from:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

To at least:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

This problem occurred to me when I updated react native from 0.61.4 to 0.64.1

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This didn't help in my case.

Comment: Nah.. this didn't help me. Any other solution for this @VictorO'Frank

Comment: I actually was forced to reduce my React native version from 0.64 to 0.63. According to the change log, the h.PlaytouchSound method introduced some breaking changes. Thus far I'm still at 0.63

Comment: Hi @VictorO'Frank today i solved this issue by doing following steps:             step 1] updating my gradle plugin version from 4.1.0 to 4.2.2                                                  step 2] gradle version from 6.5  to 6.8.3                                                              
step 3] finally deleted old  index.android.bundle and generated new index.android.bundle using " npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/ "  This may help you :)

Comment: OK, I'll look into this and report back. Thanks a mill.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i searched in android.index.bundle
h.playTouchSound
and it appear like this    `{h.playTouchSound()}`
i changed that into this

```
{h.playTouchSound(){}}
```

just added curly brackets to call a useless function
then i did the assembleRelease again and it WORKED!